# document snapshot does not exits

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Can't seem to get my document list from  firebase in flutter, even though I have added data to my document.

The way my firebase database is arranged is:

```
Computer science
    Books
        { Author : Teacher A, Title: Chemistry }
```

The code I have used to check is:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc("Books").get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) { 
     
if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print('Document exists on the database');
      } else {
        print('Document does not exist on the database');
      }
    });
```

it keeps getting to the else.

Comment: are you sure that "Books" is a document in the collection "users" ?

Comment: @FlorianPürschel yes it exists, created it in google firebase website my self.

Comment: could you please print the documentSnapshot and show what is in there?

Comment: @FlorianPürschel it shows "Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most importantly, first use `await` before you invoke the query.

Then check the spelling, if you are sure it exists, there is no reason for it not to work unless there is a typo, the names of collections and documents are case sensitive.

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc("Books").get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) { 
     
if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print('Document exists on the database');
      } else {
        print('Document does not exist on the database');
      }
    });
```

You have to await for your `get()` to finish, then perform operations on it. Otherwise, you go into your `else` condition, because to the code, you didn't wait for get to finish, therefore, there will never be a document.